# Dynamics and try/catch

Tags: c#, dynamic, try-catch

i have some code, I am writing unit tests.
So I need to check, does `serviceResult.Result.LOCATION_COUNT` exists and the rest 3 fields. I need to ensure they all do not exist. `ServiceResult.Result` is dynamic type. If some of them exists then I need to Fail the test.

```
try
        {
            Assert.IsNull(serviceResult.Result.LOCATION_AMOUNT);
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                Assert.IsNull(serviceResult.Result.OGM_AMOUNT);
            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                    Assert.IsNull(serviceResult.Result.VAT_AMOUNT);
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Assert.IsNull(serviceResult.Result.TOTAL_AMOUNT);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Assert.AreEqual(0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Assert.Fail();
```

Doesn't this code look awkward? Maybe i can better something?

Comment: you seem to be using exceptions for control flow, cant you do something like"if(serviceResult.Result.LOCATION_AMOUNT == null)Assert.True();else if(serviceResult........)"?

Comment: Seems like a good fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You don't need try catch on Unit Tests.

Comment: Are you using nunit?

Comment: You shouldn´t catch an `AssertionException`. They are the entire purpose of NUnit.

Comment: Why don't you just put all the statements in a single try/catch block? (Aside from the other issues). Don't see what multiple try/catches are giving you here

Comment: @Charleh Because if he puts all of them in a single `try`/`catch` he's going to succeed if any one of them fails, and he wants to make sure that all of them do fail.

Comment: They are all positive asserts though?

Comment: @StevenWood, i can't, because LOCATION_AMOUNT field doesn't exists.

Comment: @Pankwood, then propose something else, please.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, no, MSTEST.

Comment: @bumshakalaka Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Assert.Throws`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Throws), an assertion that a particular expression throws an exception, like this:

```
// NUnit
Assert.Throws<RuntimeBinderException>(() => serviceResult.Result.LOCATION_AMOUNT);
Assert.Throws<RuntimeBinderException>(() => serviceResult.Result.VAT_AMOUNT);    
Assert.Throws<RuntimeBinderException>(() => serviceResult.Result.LOCATION_AMOUNT);
// MSTest
ExceptionAssert.Throws(() => serviceResult.Result.LOCATION_AMOUNT);
ExceptionAssert.Throws(() => serviceResult.Result.VAT_AMOUNT);    
ExceptionAssert.Throws(() => serviceResult.Result.LOCATION_AMOUNT);
```

Comment: thanks for thoughts but this is not exactly what i want. I need to know that ALL of them do not exist. In your case code can stop at the first line and the others can exist.

Comment: @bumshakalaka Note that your observation equally applies to your code. If any of them exists, the test is going to fail. The test passes only when none of the properties exists.